# router is on .1.1 but devices on .0.1 can I move devices

Tags: lan

Had a new provider and router last week and the lan is different. The IP is 192.168.1.1 but the devices ie: firestick has IP of 192.168.0.1 I am not good with networking and scared to change anything. can someone pls help. thx x

Comment: If it ain't broken...

Comment: but the firestick will not connect it says no IP

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you still have to routers connected.  Have you changed the Fire TV Stick to use the new router.  If you are using the same router, but the IP has changed, just power off the TV Stick and turn it back on.  It should clear any IP addresses the stick has.